# Ajax send array and bool to controller method

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to send an array of objects to a controller method using AJAX, but  even after trying various methods I still won't get my desired result. This is my current code:

**View**

```
function SaveGame() {
if ('@Session["Username"]' == '@Model.Player1.Username') {
    p1 = true;
}
else {
    p1 = false;
}
var characters = document.getElementsByClassName("char");
var chardata = [];
for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    var id = characters[i].id;
    var state = characters[i].classList[1];
    chardata.push(id, state);
}
console.log(chardata);
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SaveGame", "Game")',
    type: 'GET',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'character': chardata }),
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/JSON',
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Game Saved");
        }
    });
```

}

**Gamecontroller/SaveGame**

```
public bool SaveGame(JsonDecode character)
{
    ViewGame game = (ViewGame)TempData["game"];
    TempData["game"] = game;
    return true;
    //return charLayer.SaveCharacters(game.Id, ids, states, isPlayer1);
}
```

`character` will just be null

**JsonDecode**

```
public class JsonDecode
{
    public object[] chardata { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Create a view model representing the data you are sending and use that as the parameter.

Comment: @Shyju if I do that both parameters are null

Comment: No. As long as your property names matches the JS object names. It should work.

Comment: @Shyju are you sure? I've updated my question to show you what I tried

Comment: What is the data you are trying to send ? Where are you trying to send the bool value ? You are calling push with 2 values, which will send 2 values to the array!

Comment: I'm trying to send the id and the name of the class with index 1 from each element which has classname "char". The boolean value "p1" is also something I'd like to send to the controller, but I thought I'd leave it out for now

Comment: I posted an answer with working code. Just replace the hard coded values with your code to get actual values. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is using `GET` as the type for the $.ajax call. jQuery ajax will issue a GET request to the endpoint with the data appended to the querystring of the URL it is making the call to. When you want to send simple values, it is fine, but when you want to send a complex object like what you want to send, you should use POST type.

Also, for model binding to work, the structure of the data should be similar to your view model structure and property names. Based on the data you want to send, looks like you need a view model like this.

```
public class GameStateVm
{
    public int Id { set;get;}
    public string State { set;get;}
}
public class SaveGameVm
{
    public GameStateVm[] Character { set;get;}
    public bool PFlag { set;get;}
}
```

which you can use as the parameter of your HttpPost action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveGame(SaveGameVm characters)
{   
    //  I am simply returning the posted data as it is, for testing
    //  You may return a boolean value if you want that.      
    return Json(characters);
}
```

and now in your client side code, make sure your JS object has similar strucutre and property names.

```
// JS object with same structure as our SaveGameVm
var d = { PFlag: false, character:[]}; 

d.PFlag = true;  // to do : Set the value based on your condition

// dummy code to add 2 items to the array.
// to do : replace with your code to populate the array
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   var id =i;  // to do : replace hard coded values
   var state = 'active';
   d.character.push({ id: id, state: state});
}

$.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("SaveGame", "Game")',
         type: 'POST',
         data: JSON.stringify(d),
         contentType: 'application/JSON',
         success: function (result) {
             console.log(result);
         }
});
```